# git can not connect to github

Tags: git, wifi, git-push

I'm facing strange behaviour of git and wireless network.

There are three wireless connections available. When using two of them (one of them is at home, the other - in office), I can push to github with no problem. But when I connect to the third one (this one is at home as well), the following command

```
git push origin
```

results in endless expectation of any outcome. This expectations only finishes when I break the process. By the way,

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

returns

```
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Once I connect to other networks, everything works fine.

P.S. As it was asked:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:MyName/my_repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:MyName/my_repo.git (push)
```

Comment: [What do you mean by 'expectation'?]  Could the third network be so slow that waiting is to be expected?

Comment: How are configured your remotes ? Please add `git remote -v` output to your question.

Comment: By 'expectation' I meant that the command produced NO output at all. And it lasts until I press Ctrl+C. The network is not so slow -I can easily see a movie online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ssh fails for some reason, try and switch to an https protocol:

```
git remote set-url origin https://MyName@github.com/MyName/my_repo.git
```

See if that still hangs, or if it does ask you for your GitHub's account password.

(note that you can cache those credentials with a [credential-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16901631/6309))

Comment: Thanks! The only modification I had to do was **git remote set-url origin** `https://github.com/MyName/my_repo.git`

Comment: This slight variation worked for me:  I added `url = https://github.com/MyOrganisation/my_repo.git` to my `.git/config` and commented out the usual SSH url for my remote.  This way I can put the regular setting back when I'm not on a restricted public wifi.